# How to ensure a push destination dependent on the branch?

Tags: git, github

I am going to open source one of my apps on GitHub and would like to have the following workflow:

- develop, test, and dogfood on the `dev` branch → push that branch to a **GitHub private repository** `app-dev`. This repository will have an Actions workflow with specific private elements (including a build on a self-hosted runner)
- merge findings to the `prod` branch → push that branch to a **GitHib public repository** `app-prod`, open to the public. This repository will also have a specific Actions workflow, different from the private one.

Is this possible when having on my laptop a **single** repository, with two branches, and having `git` push the right branch to the right repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `branch.<name>.pushRemote` for your branch named `<name>` and only affect it without changing your global push settings.

Check the config [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtpushRemote).